# Take an API response object and replace (map) all the keys

Tags: javascript

I'm adding some APIs to a JavaScript project to replace what used to be multi-field manual data entry with lookups. (E.g., we want to stop asking you 20 questions about a car, and instead just ask your VIN and autopopulate the other 19 answers from a VIN decoder.)

I'm spending more time than I'd like mapping data from the response schema into the existing internal schema of my app.  Lots of the work requires a human touch to suss out synonyms, like:

```
internal.postal_code = api.zipCode;
```

Some times I find myself writing a really gnarly `if` to avoid a sometimes-`null` or missing object half way down a deep tree, like

```
if(api.a && api.a.b && api.a.b.c){
  internal.z = api.a.b.c.d;
}
```

Is there a good library that would let me write a simple map and do all this work for me?  A map might look like:

```
map = {
  'zipCode' : 'postal_code',
  'a.b.c.d' : 'z'
};

mapperTool( api, internal, map );
```

(Note the `internal` object is stitched together from several APIs and pre-existing tools, so adding or overwriting properties on `internal` is better than outputting a new object.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function mapperTool(source, desc, map) {
    Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) {
        var value = key.split('.').reduce(function(obj, name) {
            if (obj && obj[name]) {
                return obj[name];
            }
        }, source);
        desc[map[key]] = value;
    });
}
var map = {
  'zipCode' : 'postal_code',
  'a.b.c.d' : 'z'
};
var internal = {};
mapperTool({a:{b:{c:{d: 10}}},zipCode:20}, internal, map);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(internal, true, 4) + '</pre>';
```